# Is there a difference between density and distribution in statistics?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm trying to find the density of the random variable Y=X^2 and i've been given an example but it shows how to find the distribution of a random variable. So I was just wondering if they were the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Density is a derivation of distribution function in case that $X$ is continous random variable. Denote $F$ distribution function and $f$ density on r.v. $X$, then
$$P(X \leq k) = F(k) = \int_{\infty}^{k} f(x) dx.$$